# Detect when at end of horizontal div, and stop

Tags: jquery, css

I've been battling with this for ages - and I'm sure it's gonna be something simple!

I have a system I'm developing, where people can embed their events calendar into their own website. This gets loaded via jQuery direct into their page. That page has a div, which is "scrolled" using `margin-left`. An example can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/hd1ayrca/4/

Working out that you are at the start of its a piece of cake.. but I can't for the life of me work out how to detect when its got to the end (and stop them scrolling any more)

It needs to be able to work responsibly (as not everyone will have a wide webpage for it to go on - some may only give it a couple of hundred px)

Can anyone help put me out of my misery! Thanks

This is a simplified version of my code, just to make it easier to see my issue <G>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare the `margin-left` value to something like `#('#test_wrapper').width()-$('#test').width()`.

You'll also need to change some CSS for `#test`. Don't set its width, so it can be as wide or narrow as the text inside. You'll need to make it have `display: inline-block` and `white-space: nowrap` so that the text stays on one long line.

Here's a modified [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hd1ayrca/6/) based on yours.

The slight jump when you scroll to the end is because the width of `#test` is not a multiple of 100.

Comment: Thanks - that works well in the fiddle, but I can't get it working on my live version. Will keep playing to see whats going on. FWIW, the reason I put a fixed width on the div, is that it will always be that size (12 months * given px width )

Comment: Got it working well now - thanks :) Can't believe it was as simple as that! Just shows that a 2nd paid of eyes really can help!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the CSS by flowstoneknight:

http://jsfiddle.net/hd1ayrca/9/

```
    $(document).on("click",'#arrow-right', function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();

        var documentWidth = $(document).width();
        var totalScroll = -1 * parseInt($('#test').css('marginLeft'));
        var elementWidth = $('#test').width();
        console.log(documentWidth, totalScroll, elementWidth);

        if((totalScroll + documentWidth  - 200) < elementWidth) {
            $('#test').css({
                marginLeft: "-=100px" 
            }, "fast");                
        }


    });
```

I also added css transitions instead of animations, this leads to smoother transitions and it's easier to check for the current position of the scroll because you don't need to take transition time into consideration

Comment: thanks, that did help. flowstoneknight did get there just before you though, so I've given him the "accepted" answer. I've "upped" you as well though, as I did use the non-animate side of things (as it has a much nicer response on iOS)